# Установка Wordpress в ветку сайта

Tags: wordpress, denwer

Создали сайт на WordPress (делали его локально через Денвер).
Пришло время в тестовом режиме переставить его на подветку сайта. Например, `http://site.ru/test/`. Т.е. по обращению по этому адресу должен открываться наш сайт на Вордпрессе, а не старый шаблон `http//site.ru` (там только html/css).

Кинул по фтп в папку `test` все файлы Вордпресса, сделал импорт БД, заменив в ней строки, где был указан локальный адрес сайта (например, `primer/` на `http://site.ru/test/`).
Сайт установлен. Главная работает без косяков, но при попытке перейти на какую-либо страницу сайта ВП, выдает ошибку `404: "Not Found. The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."`

Вопрос:
можно ли как-либо это исправить? Если да, то как?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью `.htaccess` подставив в `RewriteRule` ваш путь или в файле конфигурации в 84 строке добавить "test"

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/test');
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно зайти в админку и пересохранить данные на страницах

```
"Настройки" -> "Общие"
"Настройки" -> "Постоянные ссылки"
```

При этом перезаписываются файлы `.htaccess` в директории WP и в корне сайта и прописывается правильный путь к `index.php`. Также если у вас самописный шаблон или в плагине есть свой rewrite обработчик, то тут могу быть проблемы, если при их разработке не было учтено, что движок может быть не только в корне домена (желательно использование функций site_url, plugin_url, template_url).